# htaccess restriction on a MVC framework under laravel

Tags: .htaccess, api, laravel, restriction

Page I wanted to restrict site.com/api/v3/partner that only are available to declared IP addresses. I used,

```
<Files api> 
Deny from all 
Allow from ***.***.***.*** 
</Files>
```

But I wanted another site under still under api but on a different route which is under **v3/lt** not part of the restriction. I tried using this

```
<Files api/v3/partner>
```

so that only this page will be restricted but it won't work.

Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just used the 
RewriteCond and RewriteRule

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^***\.***\.***\.***
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/partner
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
> ```